# Could a bidet be used effectively in free fall?

Tags: microgravity, water, astronaut-lifestyle

An [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/845/without-renewable-resources-how-do-you-wipe-in-space/852#852) and a [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/845/without-renewable-resources-how-do-you-wipe-in-space#comment1412_845) on a related question, got me wondering. What would happen if you tried to use a [bidet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet) to clean up after doing your business without gravity.

Water does not behave in space the same as it does on Earth. Could a bidet be used to clean up without making a mess in the ISS?

Watch Water Become Zero-Grav Jello on the International Space Station - ICTMN.com
[image: Water]

Comment: Perhaps if the water were warmed up to reduce it's surface tension ... ?

Comment: How much impact does a few degrees have on the surface tension? I was also thinking about managing the free floating water.  In the video that goes with the image, there is ongoing water recovery during the demo.

Comment: I'd heat it so it is distinctly hot without being so hot it may scald; that would be a score or thereabouts. The [relationship](http://astarmathsandphysics.com/a-level-physics-notes/experimental-physics/a-level-physics-notes-variation-of-surface-tension-with-temperature.html) is almost linear ... better than linear if the water contains impurities.

Comment: The picture frightens me for some reason; water is scary stuff in zero gee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bidet can be used in micro-gravity, if you isolate the lower torso with a velcro-fitted cover and employ a vacuum hose to recover spent water.

However, this is rather inefficient in terms of water and electricity consumption. All of the water would be considered wastewater/"grey" water and will have to go through a series of filters and tanks/canisters. Considering the (substantial) burden of managing toilets aboard the ISS, this would reduce crew time available for science. Wet wipes are more cost-effective right now.

In terms of engineering required, a functioning bidet will be akin to a working shower. A shower, a bidet, re-usable [washable](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/653/washing-clothes-in-space-are-there-any-technical-challenges) garments and more comfortable ways of urinating and taking a dump are the basic elements of ECLSS of the future, where humans won't have to **endure** space travel but to live and relish it.