# What is a good alternative to toilet paper for space travel?

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle

So I was working on my sci-fi novel, and I stumbled across a problem: How much toilet paper do astronauts use in space? As of right now, the furthest human beings from Earth are orbiting just above our heads. So, it would be very easy to deliver new supplies and to remove waste via small cargo craft.

But, as we venture further out into space (such as to Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, or maybe even to another star), simply restocking the ship becomes pretty much impossible mid flight. So, astronauts will have to either bring everything they need with them, or generate it on board (i.e. growing food mid-flight in an garden). As the distance gets further, however, you will need to bring more supplies and materials with you; which ultimately raises the mass of the ship and requires more fuel to get there.

Because toilet paper is an expendable resource, the crew of a deep space mission would need **a lot** of it for one mission. Just a flight to Mars could require 6 months worth of TP. A flight to our nearest star, even at 1/5th the speed of light) would require almost **20 years** worth of it. In order to keep fuel costs down, ship mass light, and butts clean, we need a solution that is either renewable or (and I hate to say it) reusable for a mission beyond the Earth's orbit. So, besides just holding it in, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this crisis?

Comment: I think [Worldbuilding.se] would be your best bet (or possibly [space.se], but I don't know so much about their scope). If you want, I can migrate this question for you.

Comment: Thank you. Can you migrate this over to space exploration?

Comment: Migrating in three ... two ... one ...

Comment: I would surmise they use a form fitting toilet that creates a seal when in use with a bidet inside. Water reclaimation is already a standard practice, so wasting water cleaning bums isn't really wasting water at all.

Comment: I suggest *very* careful application of transporter technology as an alternative to paper.

Comment: @MajorStackings They actually do not, but it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/845/without-renewable-resources-how-do-you-wipe-in-space/852#852).

You would have to adapt a [Bidet](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Bidet) to space.
See also: [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/could-a-bidet-be-used-effectively-in-free-fall)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe very careful engineering could produce food which can be digested totally, with little to no waste product.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenteral_nutrition

Comment: Poor astronautes :(

Comment: The more I think about it, the more important eliminating waste production becomes. Any waste product (poo) produced by astronauts means extra mass in the food that was unnecessary, means bacterial handling, overboard dumping, or recycling equipment. For absolute best fuel economy and to keep total mass as low as possible, food should ideally produce no waste at all. Some kind of parenteral nutrition could be delivered intravenously. Whether this is in total lighter than some kind of closed ecosystem gardening is another question..

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. They psychological factor IS important. Cramp a few guys in a small tin can isolated for months with huge stress factors and deny them proper food... And you have a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The question is not about psychological factors, it is asking for alternatives to toilet paper, and explicitly mentioned mass concerns. It even mentions looking for an alternative to holding it in, and not having to poop is a perfectly valid alternative to that. I am providing a good alternative, which suggests substantial mass savings, and I provide a detailed argument and linked to reference material.

Comment: Is it a "good" alternative (cf title) remains entirely open to debate.

Comment: Its a viable answer to the proposed question, I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: I agree it's a viable answer, and I'm glad someone said it. I merely wanted to point out the limitations that comes with it. I have nothing to do with the flag that has been put on your post.